# Cant load Audio - DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, audio

I am trying to load an audio and i am getting two erros, but everything is fine and the source is correct.

errors:

- GET http://localhost:4200/src/assets/sound/welcome_Rift.mp3 404 (Not Found)
  -Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

javascript:

```
this.sound = new Audio();
        this.sound.src = 'src/assets/sound/welcome_Rift.mp3';
        this.sound.load();
        this.sound.play();
```

file path : src/assets/sound/welcome_Rift.mp3

I dont know why i am getting this eror, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

> GET http://localhost:4200/src/assets/sound/welcome_Rift.mp3 404 (Not Found)

The `404` error means that your media file has not been found. That could be a number of things. If the path is correct then it could be the localhost server which does not know where `src/assets/sound/welcome_Rift.mp3` should point towards. Might be an idea to check if a file from `src/welcome_Rift.mp3` does work to see where the problem lies.

---

> DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

This is because [`HTMLMediaElement.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) returns a `Promise`. The part where it says `Uncaught in promise` means that the promise has no way to handle the error and should add some promise logic with a `catch()` method to it. This method allows you to do something whenever an error occurs.

```
this.sound = new Audio();
this.sound.src = 'src/assets/sound/welcome_Rift.mp3';
this.sound.load();
this.sound.play()
  .then(() => {
    // Audio is playing.
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Older browsers might not return a Promise when executing `play()` so in that case you should check if it returns a promise or not.

```
this.sound = new Audio();
this.sound.src = 'src/assets/sound/welcome_Rift.mp3';
this.sound.load();
const promise = this.sound.play();
if (promise !== undefined) { // On older browsers play() does not return anything, so the value would be undefined.
  promise
    .then(() => {
      // Audio is playing.
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```